# NHibernate Navigation Property for joining only

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Take the following two entities: -

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string ItemId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDescription
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string ItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

These two entities are related by ItemId but there isn't always a ProductDescription for every ItemId that is stored against a Product.

What I want to do is set up a ProductDescription navigation property in the Product entity which I can then use in HQL in order perform joins etc. in the same way as I would any other navigation property.  I don't want there to be a foreign key or any kind of enforced relationship.

My attempt at doing was as follows: -

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string ItemId => ProductDescription?.ItemId;

    public virtual ProductDescription ProductDescription { get; set; }
}

public class ProductMap
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.ProductDescription).Not.Nullable().Column("ItemId").PropertyRef(x => x.ItemId).ForeignKey("none");
    }
}
```

This worked absolutely fine when reading existing data from the database with the navigation property working as I would expect when it comes to joins etc.

My unresolved issue is around the persistence of products. When I store a product, I don't want it to check anything to do with it's relationship with ProductDescriptions, I just want it to store the ItemId and if and when a ProductDescription with the matching ItemId is persisted, any joins that I perform using the Navigation property should work.

My attempt at persistence was as follows: -

```
new Product
{
    ProductDescription = new ProductDescription { ItemId = "SomeId" }
}
```

And this seems to work absolutely fine, until I try and make the ItemId on product non nullable at which point I get the usual error you get when you haven't set Inverse() on the other side the relation.  However, even when I did create a HasMany relationship on ProductDescription with Inverse set, it still didn't solve the issue.

I hope that the above outlines what I am trying to do.  I can get it to work almost exactly how I want except that I am forced to make the ItemId on Product nullable.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to have solved it.

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string ItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductDescription ProductDescription { get; protected set; }
}

public class ProductMap
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.ItemId).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.ProductDescription).Column("ItemId").PropertyRef(x => x.ItemId).ForeignKey("none").ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

This allows me to set the item id on either side of the relationship freely and without constraint.  The navigation property works as expected too.